# Is there a source code documentation generator for C / C++ like docco?

Tags: c++, c, documentation, implementation, docco

I would like the get a similar output on documented c++ implementation files (not header files) like the output generated with [docco](http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/). Is there such a tool?

Comment: Have you seen [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org)?

Comment: Sure, but I was looking for side by side documentation like in docco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docco claims to support this now - https://github.com/jashkenas/docco/pull/96

Answer (score 2):

the docco source (git repo) has c support.  if you clone it you can install it locally with npm.  however:

- i had to compile the docco.coffee to javascript:

  ```
  cd docco/src
  coffee -c docco.coffee
  cp docco.js ../lib
  ```
- if you have header and c files with matching names, in the same directory, one overwrites the other.
- for some reason everything node.js related is segfaulting like crazy, but i think this must be something wrong with my install (luckily, docco segfaults at the end, after generating the output).

*update* - as a fix for the overwrite issue i cloned the repo and dropped the removal of the file extension.  so `foo.h` now goes to `foo.h.html` which doesn't over-write `foo.c.html`.  you can grab a copy from https://github.com/andrewcooke/docco

i also recompiled the javascript, so to use do something like:

```
git clone git://github.com/andrewcooke/docco.git
npm install docco
docco src/*.c src/*.h
```

Comment: Above links no longer active

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with docco, but it looks like a form of literate programming.  If this is the case, you might want to look at [cweb](http://www-cs-staff.stanford.edu/~uno/cweb.html).  The syntax is probably different, but it does work with C++ (even if it was designed with C in mind).